# When generating a SHA256 / 512 hash, is there a minimum 'safe' amount of data to hash?

Tags: hash, checksum, sha

I have heard that when creating a hash, it's possible that if small files or amounts of data are used, the resulting hash is more likely to suffer from a collision. If that is true, is there a minimum "safe" amount of data that should be used to ensure this doesn't happen?

I guess the question could also be phrased as:

What is the smallest amount of data that can be safely and securely hashed?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

A hash function accepts inputs of arbitrary (or at least very high) length, and produces a fixed-length output. There are more possible inputs than possible outputs, so collisions must exist. The whole point of a secure hash function is that it is "collision resistant", which means that while collisions must mathematically exist, it is very very hard to actually compute one. Thus, there is no known collision for SHA-256 and SHA-512, and the best known methods for computing one (by doing it *on purpose*) are so ludicrously expensive that they will not be applied soon (the whole US federal budget for a century would buy only a ridiculously small part of the task).

So, if it cannot be realistically done *on purpose*, you can expect not to hit a collision out of (bad) luck.

Moreover, if you limit yourself to very short inputs, there is a chance that there is no collision *at all*. E.g., if you consider 12-byte inputs: there are 2<sup>96</sup> possible sequences of 12 bytes. That's huge (more than can be enumerated with today's technology). Yet, SHA-256 will map each input to a 256-bit value, i.e. values in a much wider space (of size 2<sup>256</sup>). We cannot prove it formally, but chances are that all those 2<sup>96</sup> hash values are distinct from each other. Note that this has no practical consequence: there is no measurable difference between not finding a collision because there is none, and not finding a collision because it is extremely improbable to hit one.

Just to illustrate how low risks of collision are with SHA-256: consider your risks of being mauled by a gorilla escaped from a local zoo or private owner. Unlikely? Yes, but it still may conceivably happen: it seems that a gorilla escaped from the [Dallas zoo in 2004](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/4558461/ns/us_news/) and injured four persons; another gorilla escaped from the [same zoo in 2010](http://www.upi.com/Top_News/US/2010/02/14/Escaped-gorilla-recaptured-at-Dallas-Zoo/UPI-15751266174950/). Assuming that there is only one rampaging gorilla every 6 years on the whole Earth (not only in the Dallas area) and you happen to be the unlucky chap who is on his path, out of a human population of 6.5 billions, then risks of grievous-bodily-harm-by-gorilla can be estimated at about 1 in 2<sup>43.7</sup> per day. Now, take 10 *thousands* of PC and have them work on finding a collision for SHA-256. The chances of hitting a collision are close to 1 in 2<sup>75</sup> per day -- more than a *billion* less probable than the angry ape thing. The conclusion is that if you fear SHA-256 collisions but do not keep with you a loaded shotgun at all times, then you are getting your priorities wrong. Also, do not mess with Texas.

Comment: I either need to move, or keep the guns closer to my bed.

Comment: I think the gorilla attack probability should be adjusted as there was at least one more gorille escape in 2007 in The Netherlands. ;) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokito_(gorilla)

Comment: That was a fantastic example of probability.

Answer (score 3):

There is no minimum input size. SHA-256 algorithm is effectively a random mapping and collision probability doesn't depend on input length. Even a 1 bit input is 'safe'.

Note that the input is padded to a multiple of 512 bits (64 bytes) for SHA-256 (multiple of 1024 for SHA-512). Taking a 12 byte input (as Thomas used in his example), when using SHA-256, there are 2^96 possible sequences of length 64 bytes.

As an example, a 12 byte input *Hello There!* (0x48656c6c6f20546865726521) will be padded with a one bit, followed by 351 zero bits followed by the 64 bit representation of the length of the input in bits which is 0x0000000000000060 to form a 512 bit padded message. This 512 bit message is used as the input for computing the hash.

More details can be found in RFC: 4634 "US Secure Hash Algorithms (SHA and HMAC-SHA)", http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4634.txt

Answer (score 2):

No, message length does not effect the likeliness of a collision.

If that were the case, the algorithm is broken.

You can try for yourself by running SHA against all one-byte inputs, then against all two-byte inputs and so on, and see if you get a collision. Probably not, because no one has ever found a collision for SHA-256 or SHA-512 (or at least they [kept it a secret from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions))

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it likely but I thought it was prudent to check.

Answer (score 0):

Τhe hash is 256 bits long, there is a collision for anything longer than 256bits.

Υou cannot compress something into a smaller thing without having collisions, its defying mathmatics.

Yes, because of the algoritm and the 2 to the power of 256 there is a lot of different hashes, but they are not collision free, that is impossible.

Answer (score -4):

Depends very much on your application: if you were simply hashing "YES" and "NO" strings to send across a network to indicate whether you should give me a $100,000 loan, it would be a pretty big failure -- the domain of answers can't be *that* large, so someone could easily check observed hashes on the wire against a database of 'small input' hash outputs.

If you were to include the date, time, my name, my tax ID, the amount requested, the amount of data being hashed probably won't amount to much, but the chances of that data being in precomputed hash tables is pretty slim.

But I know of no research to point you to beyond my instincts. Sorry.

Comment: The ability to brute-force a small input domain (YES and NO) in order to reverse the hash function does not constitute a collision.

Comment: The OP is not talking about collisions of the same string, but different strings instead.